# Store sqlite3 table names in a bash array

Tags: bash, sqlite

I'm trying to figure out how to store the table names containing a geometry field from a sqlite3 database into a bash array that I can loop on afterwards.

Here's what I have but it's empty for the moment:

```
CMD="SELECT f_table_name FROM geometry_columns;"    
readarray -t arr < <( `sqlite3 db.sqlite "$CMD"` )
```

I also tried:

```
readarray -t arr < <( sqlite3 db.sqlite ".tables" )
```

But it contains only 1 element when I print `echo ${arr}`, where there should be many. Which I don't understand because

```
echo $(sqlite3 db.sqlite ".tables" )
```

dumps all the table names to stdout.

Any idea on how to achieve that in the most simple and efficient way?
Ideally using `readarray`, or any other single-line universal enough solution to work in a simple Debian docker container.

I don't see any trouble writing a temporary file holding the necessary data on the disk.

Comment: store to a temporary file and read from that could be an option?

Comment: i see table in the CMD= and tables after, perhaps a typo ?

Comment: Updated. I figure out how to get names of tables which actuall contain a geometry field. If I paste that SELECT statement when I'm logged into the sqlite3 db, it prints what it does.

Comment: it works for me too, i used `printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"` to dump the content of the array on stdout.

Comment: Nevermind, I think the problem was with `echo` which only prints the first line of the array (where I was expecting `echo` to print all the content of the array).

Answer (score 2):

For the posterity

```
CMD="SELECT f_table_name FROM geometry_columns;"

readarray -t arr < <( sqlite3 db.sqlite "${CMD}" )

for t in "${arr[@]}"; 
do
  echo "${t}"
done
```

actually prints each line of the array (it's a structure composed of lines, apparently). I was expecting a simple `echo ${arr}` to print all the content to stdout by default, which is not the case, you have to loop over it.

Please notice to not include the backticks ` ` or to equivalently put the whole sqlite3 command in `$()` for this to work.

Comment: "it's a structure composed of lines, apparently" -- yes, that's exactly what `readarray` is for, reading lines into an array. And `${arr}` is the same as `${arr[0]}`, so it only prints the first element. This would be different in Zsh, though.